# How to fix this error in Xampp?

Tags: xampp, windows-7-x64

I downloaded xampp on win7 64 bit , but when press on Apache to start, appear red message.

```js
11:22:54 م  [Apache]  Apache Service detected with wrong path
11:22:54 م  [Apache]  Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or
11:22:54 م  [Apache]  Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
11:22:54 م  [Apache]  Found Path: "C:\Apache24\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
11:22:54 م  [Apache]  Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
11:22:54 م  [Apache]  XAMPP Apache is already running on port 443
11:22:54 م  [mysql]  XAMPP MySQL is already running on port 3306
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you already have Apache running from a different client, you should check your other services and see if they're running and if they are stop them.